# How to modify the size of RAM requirement of aurora task in Heron cluster deployed on Aurora scheduler?

Tags: mesos, heron, apache-aurora

I deployed `Heron cluster` using `aurora-scheduler` and `Mesos`. And when I ran the default `WordCountTopology` using this cluster, I found the `ram` demand of aurora task is `4G`. However, the WordCountToplogy's configuration as follows:

```
componentRam: 1G
containerRamRequested: 1G
containerCpuRequested: 2 cores
containerDiskRequeted: 2G
```

Aurora task.json content is:
[image]

It shows that this task of aurora needs 4g ram resources. But I don't know why it requests 4G ram. And how to modified this ram requirement?
In addition, there are two slave hosts in my heron cluster and these host resources is:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the Ram requested by topology's components, there are some additional resources(cpu, memory) requested for heron's daemon processes,e.g `stream-manager`. [Packing additional CPU in RR](https://github.com/apache/incubator-heron/blob/58078e7c349af4c420713a9aa37fc13670291f17/heron/packing/src/java/org/apache/heron/packing/roundrobin/RoundRobinPacking.java#L310)

A second cause for the larger resource request is due to Aurora only allows homogeneous containers. The packing algorithm will pick maximum container resources as the resource request for all the containers. For example, if a topology has two containers: one requests 2 cpus and the other requests 3 cpus. Then the eventually all containers will request 3 cpus.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already understood this question by reading RR packing algorithm codes.